# Session class DOES NOT Exist on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am currently using Parse as the backend for a mobile app. I just noticed that the Session class does not exist on the dashboard, and I couldn't find a way to make it appear. Although I'm pretty sure it is there because my app works fine as users can login (and stay logged in until logout) without issues.

According to Parse.com this should automatically created. I currently have Installation, User, Role, and custom classes I created myself.

It is driving me crazy as I am going to migrate to Parse Server, but I just can't find the Session class, it is not being migrated to the destination Mongo DB either.  This means as soon as I switch to Parse Server, users will start getting 'Invalid session token' errors.

Btw I have a staging environment, the Session class does exist on there, but not on my production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Session class will be automatically created, if it doesn't already exist, by Parse Server once a User signs up or logs in.

If you are migrating from Parse.com to your own Parse Server, you should have migrated the MongoDB database to a hosting provider (ex. mLab). This should have migrated all of your Users, Sessions, and all other data. To verify this, you should be able to view the collections in your MongoDB database: there are a lot of MongoDB admin tools freely available for this. You should check your database for a `_Session` collection.

You should then be able to bring up the open source Parse Dashboard, and see both your User and Session table with records with all session tokens to still be valid.

***If you have a _User collection in your database, but no _Session collection***: either the database migration had an issue or you never turned on the new **Parse Revocable Sessions** for your users (which means the session token is actually stored inside the each _User record). The way to check this on the Parse.com dashboard is in the Settings area for your app. If so, you should take a look at enabling revocable sessions. You should make sure you are using the latest SDKs, Parse Server and Parse Dashboard.

If you see a Session class on the Parse.com dashboard, and no Session class using an open source Parse Dashboard pointing to your Parse Server, then there must be a misconfiguration on your Parse Server, as they both should be pointing to the same MongoDB database with the revocable Session settings.

This is as much info as I can provide without knowing additional details of your system setup or how you migrated. But hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was indeed due to Parse Revocable Sessions wasn't set up. Somehow I missed this important noticed from Parse back in Mar 2015. Luckily this didn't cause a huge issue as the user base was still low. Just had to inform them to upgrade to a newer version of the app. :)